# How to scrape Wikipedia GPS latitude/longitude?

Tags: shell, web-scraping, gps, screen-scraping, wikipedia

I have been wondering how is it possible to scrap Wikipedia information. For example, I have a list of world cities and want to obtain their approximate latitude and longitude. Take Miami as an example. When I type `curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami | grep -E '(latitude|longitude)'`, somewhere in the HTML there will be a tag mark like below.

`<span class="latitude">25°46′31″N</span> <span class="longitude">80°12′31″W</span>`

I know I can extract it with some regex string, but I speak a very poor regexish. Can some of you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
$ xidel -se '
    concat(
        (//span[@class="latitude"]/text())[1],
        " ",
        (//span[@class="longitude"]/text())[1]
    )
' 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami'
```

### Output

```
25°46′31″N 80°12′31″W
```

Or

```
saxon-lint --html --xpath '<XPATH EXP>' <URL>
```

If you want most known tools:

```
curl -s 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami' > Miami.html
xmlstarlet format -H Miami.html 2>/dev/null | sponge Miami.html
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '<XPATH EXP>' Miami.html
```

---

Not mentioned, but regex are not the right tool to parse HTML

Comment: Haha! So fast and furious I could not even think.

Comment: You're welcome, added 2 other solutions

Comment: I looked for command `saxon-lint` and found you as author. Very impressive

Comment: I tried to a one-command run to install your saxon-lint?

Comment: Which OS/distro ?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 20.X

Comment: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/06f0746a2e5725e318f5d52d5380b0a9/raw/70c0a0c21db9f03a73b8114823fd4b0edff49ed9/install%2520saxon-lint

Comment: Fixed double latitude echo-ed, and added longitude ;)

Comment: The output is always somewhat XXºYY'ZZ"S. It should be something like the following `(S=='W' ? -1 : 1) XX+YY/60+ZZ/3600` ni pseudo-code. Is it simple to do it in shell script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249999/discussion-between-gilles-quenot-and-bruno-peixoto).

Answer (score 1):

[You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) [parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747) [with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105). Please use an HTML-parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead:

```
$ xidel -s "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami" -e '
  (//span[@class="geo-dms"])[1],
  (//span[@class="geo-dec"])[1],
  (//span[@class="geo"])[1],
  replace((//span[@class="geo"])[1],";",())
'
25°46′31″N 80°12′31″W
25.775163°N 80.208615°W
25.775163; -80.208615
25.775163 -80.208615
```

Take your pick.

Comment: @Gilles Quenot the first URL link is pure gold. I recommend for laughing.

Comment: How can I install `xidel` on Ubuntu?

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto I think https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/238226/476158 would be useful. I'm not a Linux user myself.